# Handle Cell Button in GridView in C#

Tags: c#, button, gridview

I'm working in C# project, I made a `GridView` and I already made a `Button` in one column. When I press the `Button` I want to open `Dialog` form, I did experimental code showing a message when I press it, the experimental code as below:

```
    void dataGridViewShowCourse_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        //make sure click not on header and column is type of ButtonColumn
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && ((DataGridView)sender).Columns[e.ColumnIndex].GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewButtonColumn))
        {
             //TODO - Execute Code Here
            MessageBox.Show("I pressed CellButton");
        }
    }
```

And to call CellContentClick I did this code:

```
    public void showCourse()
    {
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [Course_ID]
                                              ,[CourseCreated].[CourseCreated_Name]
                                              ,[CourseCreated].[CourseCreated_Type]
                                              ,[Course_Hours]
                                              ,[Course_Duration]
                                              ,[Course_Place]
                                              ,[Trainer_Info].[Trainer_Name]
                                          FROM [VolunteersAffairs].[dbo].[Course_Info],[CourseCreated], [Trainer_Info]
                                          where [Course_Info].[CourseCreated_ID] = [CourseCreated].[CourseCreated_ID] and [Trainer_Info].[Trainer_ID] = [Course_Info].[Trainer_ID]", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet dats = new DataSet();
        da.SelectCommand = com;
        da.Fill(dats, "Course_Info");
        dataGridViewShowCourse.DataSource = null;
        dataGridViewShowCourse.Columns.Clear();
        dataGridViewShowCourse.DataSource = dats.Tables["Course_Info"];
        DataGridViewButtonColumn col = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
        col.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
        col.Text = "ِِAdd";
        col.Name = "stedents";
        col.HeaderText = "Got Course";
        dataGridViewShowCourse.Columns.Add(col);
        //Here is my Event Handler
        dataGridViewShowCourse.CellContentClick += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridViewShowCourse_CellContentClick);
    }
```

**When I press that button for first time every thing is worked fine, But the problem is that when I add some rows the code executed many times, meant that the message appears one time for first time before adding any row, and if I add one more row the message appears twice, three times...etc. Or when I press the first row the message appears one time, second row the message appears twice, third row the message appears three time....etc.**

Please tell me me where is the error.

Note* the function  `showCourse()` called here:

```
    public AddCourses()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        showCourse();
        FillComboBoxCourseName();
        comboBoxCourseName.SelectedItem = null;
        FillComboBoxTrainerName();
        comboBoxTrainers.SelectedItem = null;
    }
```

And here is the button where I call again the ShowCourse()

```
private void buttonAddCourse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            CourseClass c = (CourseClass)comboBoxCourseName.SelectedItem;
            //SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("update Course_Info set Course_Hours=\' \'where Course_ID = " + c.ID, con);
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO [VolunteersAffairs].[dbo].[Course_Info]
                                                       ([CourseCreated_ID]
                                                       ,[Course_Hours]
                                                       ,[Course_Duration]
                                                       ,[Course_Place]
                                                       ,[Trainer_ID])
                                                 VALUES
                                                       (@CourseCreatedID
                                                       ,@CourseHours
                                                       ,@CourseDuration
                                                       ,@CoursePlace
                                                       ,@TrainerID)", con);
            com.Parameters.Add("@CourseCreatedID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (comboBoxCourseName.SelectedItem as CourseClass).ID;
            com.Parameters.Add("@CourseHours", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = textBoxCourseHours.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@CourseDuration", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = textBoxCourseDuration.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@CoursePlace", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = textBoxCoursePlace.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add("@TrainerID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (comboBoxTrainers.SelectedItem as CourseClass).ID;
            con.Open();
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            showCourse(); // Here is the Function
            FillComboBoxCourseName();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                con.Close();
            MessageBoxEx.Show("Please Try Again", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your event handler code you are re-assigning the event handler again and again...

```
void dataGridViewShowCourse_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        // Problem is in this line, re-assigning the same event handler again to the same event
        // event handler will execute more than 1 time and number of execution will also keep increasing each time
        dataGridViewShowCourse.CellContentClick += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridViewShowCourse_CellContentClick);
        //make sure click not on header and column is type of ButtonColumn
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && ((DataGridView)sender).Columns[e.ColumnIndex].GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewButtonColumn))
        {
             //TODO - Execute Code Here
            MessageBox.Show("I pressed CellButton");
        }
    }
```

you have the following line of code in your "showCourse" method, therefore you don't need to assign it again

```
dataGridViewShowCourse.CellContentClick += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridViewShowCourse_CellContentClick);
```

To solve the problem you need to assign the event handler in another function as below

```
public void showCellButton()
    {
        dataGridViewShowCourse.CellContentClick += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridViewShowCourse_CellContentClick);
    }
```

Comment: | one part has been solved which is the message does not recall when I Press the button before do any thing. But the problem is still where I add new row. Please look at the Function CourseShow(), I called the eventHandler at the last line

Comment: when you add new row, do you also call the "showCourse" method?

Comment: Yes Sir, I called it again, because I need to show the new added row

Comment: "showCourse" will also register the event handler again and again. You need to register the event handler only once in your code for the "dataGridViewShowCourse"

Comment: can I did it in another function?!

Comment: yes, do it in another function. Make sure, you call it only once.

Comment: Sir, Will you update your answer to make it as the right answer. IT IS DONE, THANKS ^_^