# MessageBox appearing twice on clickevent

Tags: c#

I have this code here,
When I click on the *Modify button*, I got a message box. After I click on the `x` button to close it, the message box appears again. I really don't know why this happens.

```
private void dataGridUsers_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridUsers.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn &&
        e.RowIndex >= -1 && dataGridUsers.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Modify")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("");
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem isn't with that code, that code's fine. The problem is with the invocation of your `CellContentClick` handler.

Comment: And what should i do?

Comment: Show us the code where you 'wire up' that event handler.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handle Cell Button in GridView in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036051/handle-cell-button-in-gridview-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @DeeMac, i just do this here:             dataGridUsers.CellContentClick += dataGridUsers_CellContentClick;

Comment: gotit, i assigned it twice somewhere :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Guess: You are *re-assigning* the event handler again and again somewhere in your code. That is the problem you are getting the message box triggered twice.

```
dataGridUsers.CellContentClick += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridUsers_CellContentClick);
```

To fix the issue, you need to assign the above event handler only in the function where you need.